# Trying to advance the Python Code past the IndexError: and continue

Tags: python, json, indexing

please help, I'm new to Python and have been working on this for hours. I'm trying to run a particular JSON code, but it's unknown whether the JSON list will be 16, 15, 14, or 13 parts in length. So I would like to have the code run until it hits the highest possible number. 
This is what I have:

```
import requests     
api_address = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily? 
zip=10603&cnt=16&appid=fe0b46e2c4f3c410fc3f8ac8d3a17600&q'          
zip_code =  79326   
url = api_address + str(zip_code)           
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
formatted_data1 = json_data['list'][16]['temp']
formatted_data2 = json_data['list'][15]['temp']
formatted_data3 = json_data['list'][14]['temp']
formatted_data4 = json_data['list'][13]['temp']
try:
print (formatted_data1)
    try:
    print (formatted_data2) 
        try:
        print (formatted_data3) 
            try:
            print (formatted_data4)
```

I'm getting a "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" error from this but I'm running this to avoid the "IndexError: list index out of range" when I have

```
"print(formatted_data1, formatted_data2, formatted_data3, formatted_data4) "
```

at the end

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SyntaxError` is cause by wrong indentation

```
# Error
try:
print (formatted_data1)

# No Error
try:
    print (formatted_data1)
```

`IndexError` is cause by trying to access value beyond valid index. For example, `a` is `length` of `3`, all valid access to `a` is `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`. If you try to get a[3] you will get `IndexError`

Following code

```
a = ['a','b','c']
print(len(a))
print(a[3])
```

yeild

```
$ python test.py
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
          print(a[3])
          IndexError: list index out of range
```

Normally the error message will tell you where the error is, for example `File "test.py", line 3` as above message.

I am not sure if you only want is the last value or not.

If it is the case try using `len` function to get the length before try getting the value to ensure you will never try to get beyond the last one. `- 1` because it `zero-based index`

```
import requests

api_address = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=10603&cnt=16&appid=fe0b46e2c4f3c410fc3f8ac8d3a17600&q'
zip_code =  79326
url = api_address + str(zip_code)
json_data = requests.get(url).json()

data_length = len(json_data['list']) - 1
print(data_length)

formatted_data = json_data['list'][data_length]['temp']
print(formatted_data)
```

**Tips for debugging**: use `print` function to print out the value and see if it is make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving your Syntax Error because you're not pairing your **try**s with any **except**s.

```
try:
    print(formatted_data1)
except:
    print('These excepts are necessary')
try:
    print (formatted_data2) 
except:
    print('These excepts are necessary')
try:
    print (formatted_data3) 
except:
    print('These excepts are necessary')
try:
    print (formatted_data4)
except:
    print('These excepts are necessary')
```

As for the problem you're trying to solve itself, your approach could be improved using something like...

```
parts = json_data['list']
```

... to do something like ...

```
for p in parts:
    print(p['temp'])
```

Comment: I don't believe a `try` without an `except` will cause `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.  That is certainly an error, but he must have another error somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnGordon Following try, the python interpreter awaits except and will throw either EOF or Invalid Syntax syntax errors if it doesn't get it.

Answer (score -1):

The `IndexError` happens when you try to *access* the data, not *print* it, so putting `try` blocks around the print statements is too late.

But a better solution would be to not use `try` at all; instead you can look at the length of the list so you don't have to guess how many elements are present:

```
if len(json_data['list']) >= 14:
    print (json_data['list'][13]['temp'])
if len(json_data['list']) >= 15:
    print (json_data['list'][14]['temp'])
if len(json_data['list']) >= 16:
    print (json_data['list'][15]['temp'])
if len(json_data['list']) >= 17:
    print (json_data['list'][16]['temp'])
```